# Estimating accuracy from raw NMEA data

Tags: gps, accuracy, nmea, usb

I am developing an android app for a usb GPS module of UBLOX. Is there any accuracy information in the raw NMEA data which i can use in my GUI? or do I have to use any algorithm to calculate the accuracy?

Comment: Did you see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195241/working-out-meter-accuracy-based-on-number-of-visible-gps-satellites?rq=1  could the answer posted in the comment work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the NMEA xxGST message, e.g. GPGST for GPS satellites.  See section section 18.12 of the u-blox Receiver Description Protocol Reference document for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot, in my case GNGST was disabled, I enable it from configurations of gps. it gives:
-> Standard deviation of latitude error in m.
-> Standard deviation of longitude error in m.
-> Standard deviation of altitude error in m.

Should I take a mean of all 3 values to find my 3D accuracy?

Comment: Please see the formulas here: https://gnss-sdr.org/design-forces/accuracy/ You can take MRSE = Math.sqrt(latitudeError * latitudeError + longitudeError * longitudeError +  heightError * heightError)